# How to check for preceding substring of elements with XSLT 1.0?

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

I'll set an example for you to see my :

Here's my xml :

```
<object>
   <name>T3-A-blablabla</name>
</object>
<object>
   <name>T3-A-blablabla</name>
</object>
<object>
   <name>T3-B-blablabla</name>
</object>
<object>
   <name>T2-A-blablabla</name>
</object>
<object>
   <name>T2-A-blablabla</name>
</object>
```

And this is my for-each loop :

```
<xsl:for-each select="object[not(substring(name, '0', '6') = substring(preceding::object/name, '0', '6'))]">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So I want to only look for the objects with different "types" (T3-A- , T3-B- , T2-A- and so on ..).

My actual loop gives me this :

```
T3-A-blablabla
T3-B-blablabla
T2-A-blablabla
T2-A-blablabla
```

But I would like this :

```
T3-A-blablabla
T3-B-blablabla
T2-A-blablabla
```

But my loop only exclude the first object, as if preceding was not checking for all the precedent objects possibly conflicting with the substring function. 
Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this task you have to use a technique called [`Muenchian Grouping`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=muenchian+grouping).
Applied to your specific problem setting this results in the following stylesheet/template using a *composite key* which is, in your case, `concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'))`.

This *composite key* reduces a string like `T3-A-blablabla` to `T3-A` which is then used as a *key* for `xsl:key` in the *Muenchian* setting.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ...
<xsl:key name="type" match="object" use="concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'))"/> 
...

<xsl:template match="/root">
   <xsl:for-each select="object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type',concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')))[1])]">
     <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course you have to replace the `match="/root"` with the actual context of the `object` nodes.
The output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tr>
  <td>
   T3-A-blablabla
</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>
   T3-B-blablabla
</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>
   T2-A-blablabla
</td>
</tr>
```